# Java Stream api как вернуть обработанный поток

Tags: java

Изучаю Java, делаю задачу по stream api, но решение не проходит.

Есть функция принимающая поток строк
public static Stream  x (Stream >String> value)

Далее поток value разбивается по разделителю, сортируется и преобразуется в Map.
Вопрос: return функции должен возвращать поток, но как вернуть значение преобразованного потока, ведь после терминальной операции он исчезает ?

Comment: Вероятно не стоит выполнять терминальную операцию.

Comment: "промежуточные методы выполняются только при наличии терминального метода" из Java 8 Stream Tutorial, если я правильно все понимаю.

Comment: Половина смысла потоков в их ленивости. Вы объявляете операции, которые необходимо выполнить над данными, а выполняться они потом, когда данные фактически понадобятся.

Comment: Если это не придуманная вами задача, то скиньте ее исходное условие.

Comment: @sam и зачем вы удалили вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После выполнения терминальной операции поток закрывается и больше не может быть переиспользован. Все промежуточные результаты лучше хранить в коллекциях.
Но если так уж необходимо иметь стрим и применять к нему разные терминальные операции, то можно воспользоваться Supplier'ом, умеющим возвращать требуемый Stream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] values = {"c,b,a", "f,e,d", "i,h,g"};
    Supplier<Stream<String>> resultStreamSupplier = () -> fun(values, ",");
    System.out.println("1) Count: " + resultStreamSupplier.get().count());
    System.out.println("2) Joining: " + resultStreamSupplier.get().collect(Collectors.joining()));
    System.out.println("3) Map: " + resultStreamSupplier.get().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, String::toUpperCase)));
}

public static Stream<String> fun(String[] values, String splitter) {
    return Stream.of(values).flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split(splitter))).sorted();
}
```